# Comparing two strings, both with regex

Tags: java, regex, security, permissions

I'm implementing a security system on my application and I'm having some problems to check if user `x` has permission `y`.

Well, let's contextualize:
E.g: My app have these permissions:

- `cmd.a`
- `cmd.b`
- `api.a`
- `api.b`

The admins have the following permissions available: `*.a` (`*` means everything, so it's `cmd.a` and `api.a`), and normal users have `*.b` (`cmd.b` and `api.b`).

So I have to compare if a user have `cmd.a`.
Well, how do I compare `*.a` with `cmd.a`?
And what about comparing `*.a` to `cmd.*` (`cmd.a`, `cmd.b`) (must be false, cause `*.a` includes only `cmd.a` and `api.a`)?

I honestly don't know where to start, since I will not know the existing permissions on runtime (`cmd.a`, `cmd.b`, `api.a`, `api.b`), I just have the permissions that the user have (E.g. `*.a`) and a permission (`*` can appear) to compare (E.g. `cmd.*` or `cmd.foo`, etc).

I realy don't know if i explained correctly what I want. How can I compare these regex expressions?

Comment: What have you tried? You list regex as the problem, but haven't included any of that code. Try looking up a regex tutorial. The pattern `*.a` when compiled using a regex library will be able to perform this match as you described.

Answer (score 0):

These aren't regular expressions. Something like `cmd\\..*` would be a regular expression (which would match cmd.a and would not match api.a).

First write this method:

```
public static boolean matches(String permission, String config) {
    // you write it!
}
```

which acts as follows:

```
public static void test() {
    assertTrue(matches("cmd.a", "cmd.*"));
    assertFalse(matches("cmd.a", "api.*"));
    assertTrue(matches("cmd.b", "*.b"));
    assertFalse(matches("cmd.b", "*.a"));
}
```

once you have that, the rest should be simple. I don't think you should use regular expressions to implement matches, but you can if you truly want to. Make sure you use the Pattern.quote feature if you do, though!